# Finding the mathematical expectation

Tags: solution-verification, expected-value, uniform-distribution

For defined in the condition of random values:

If the components are XI=(XI1;XI2) are independent, then calculate the conditional mathematical expectation of E(min{XI1; XI2}|max{XI1; XI2}), otherwise find E(XI1|XI2).

The random values of the XI1 and XI2 are evenly distributed in the quadrangle with peaks (2, 2), (1, -2), (-2, -2), (-2, 2).

My solution:

$E(min(\xi_{1};\xi_{2})|max(\xi_{1};\xi_{2}))=E(V|Z);$

$F_\xi(z)=P(Z<z)=P(max(\xi_{1};\xi_{2})<z)=P(\xi_{1}<z)\cdot P(\xi_{2}<z)= F_{\xi_{1}}(z)\cdot F_{\xi_{2}}(z);$

$f_z(z)=f_{\xi_1}(z)\cdot F_{\xi_{2}}(z)+F_{\xi_{1}}(z)\cdot f_{\xi_2}(z);$

$F_{y;z}(y;z)=P(min(\xi_1;\xi_2)<y|max(\xi_1;\xi_2)<z)=P(max(\xi_1;\xi_2)<z)-P(min(\xi_1;\xi_2)>=y,max(\xi_1;\xi_2)<z)=F_{\xi_{1}}(z)\cdot F_{\xi_{2}}(z)-(F_{\xi_{1}}(z)-F_{\xi_{1}}(y))\cdot(F_{\xi_{2}}(z)-F_{\xi_{1}}(y));$

$f_{y;z}(y;z)=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y\partial z}(F_{y|z}(y;z))=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y\partial z}(F_{\xi_{1}}(z)\cdot F_{\xi_{2}}(z)-(F_{\xi_{1}}(z)-F_{\xi_{1}}(y))\cdot(F_{\xi_{2}}(z)-F_{\xi_{2}}(y)))=\frac{\partial}{\partial z}(f_{\xi_{1}}(y)\cdot F_{\xi_{2}}(z)+f_{\xi_{1}}(y)\cdot F_{\xi_{2}}(z)-(f_{\xi_{1}}(y)\cdot F_{\xi_{2}}(y)+f_{\xi_{2}}(y)\cdot F_{\xi_{1}}(y)))=f_{\xi_{1}}(z)\cdot f_{\xi_{2}}(y)+f_{\xi_{1}}(y)\cdot f_{\xi_{2}}(z);$

$f_{y|z}(y|z)=\dfrac{f(y;z)^{'}(y;z)}{f_z(z)}=\dfrac{f_{\xi_{1}}(z)\cdot f_{\xi_{2}}(y)+f_{\xi_{1}}(y)\cdot f_{\xi_{2}}(z)}{f_{\xi_{1}}(z)\cdot F_{\xi_{2}}(z)+F_{\xi_{1}}(z)\cdot f_{\xi_{2}}(z)};$

$F_{y|z}(y;z)_1=\dfrac{f_{\xi_{11}}(z)\cdot f_{\xi_{2}}(y)+f_{\xi_{11}}(y)\cdot f_{\xi_{2}}(z)}{f_{\xi_{11}}(z)\cdot F_{\xi_{2}}(z)+F_{\xi_{11}}(z)\cdot f_{\xi_{2}}(z)};$

$F_{y|z}(y;z)_2=\dfrac{f_{\xi_{12}}(z)\cdot f_{\xi_{2}}(y)+f_{\xi_{12}}(y)\cdot f_{\xi_{2}}(z)}{f_{\xi_{12}}(z)\cdot F_{\xi_{2}}(z)+F_{\xi_{12}}(z)\cdot f_{\xi_{2}}(z)};$

$F_{y|z}(y;z)=F_{y|z}(y;z)_1+F_{y|z}(y;z)_2;$

${E_{y|z}}_1=\int^{2}_{-2} y\cdot F_{y|z}(y;z)_1\,dy;$

${E_{y|z}}_2=\int^{2}_{-2} y\cdot F_{y|z}(y;z)_2\,dy;$

$E_{y|z}={E_{y|z}}_1+{E_{y|z}}_2.$

```
FXi2[y_]=Integrate[fXi2[y],{y,-2,y}]

FXi11[x_]=Integrate[fXi11[x],{x,-2,x}]

FXi12[x_]=Integrate[fXi12[x],{x,4*x-6,x}]

FXi1[x_]=FXi11[x]+FXi12[x]//FullSimplify

Fyz11[y_,z_]=(fXi11[z]*fXi2[y]+fXi11[y]*fXi2[z])*(fXi11[z]*FXi2[z]+FXi11[z]*fXi2[z])//FullSimplify

Fyz12[y_,z_]=(fXi12[z]*fXi2[y]+fXi12[y]*fXi2[z])*(fXi12[z]*FXi2[z]+FXi12[z]*fXi2[z])//FullSimplify

Fyz[y_,z_]=Fyz11[y,z]+Fyz12[y,z]//FullSimplify

Eyz11[z_]=Integrate[y*Fyz11[y,z],{y,-2,2}]//FullSimplify

Eyz12[z_]=Integrate[y*Fyz12[y,z],{y,4*x-6,2}]//FullSimplify

Eyz[z_]=Eyz12[z]+Eyz11[z]//FullSimplify
```

Calculation results:

photo № 1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlgUw.png

photo № 2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0XuA.png

photo № 3: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeQbp.png

Please check my solution. Tell me where there are errors and how you would correct them.